# Why does this happen when rounding floating numbers in Python?

Tags: python, floating-accuracy

I am looking into rounding floating point numbers in Python and the following behavior seems quite strange:

**Code**:

```
a = 203.25
print '%.2f'%(a/10.)
print '%.2f'%(round(a/10., 2))
print '%.2f'%(0.1*a)
```

**Output**:

```
20.32
20.32
20.33
```

Why does the first and especially the second case fail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

> **Round half to even**
>   A tie-breaking rule that is less biased is **round half to even**, namely:
>
> If the fraction of y is 0.5, then q is the even integer nearest to y.
>   Thus, for example, +23.5 becomes +24, as does +24.5; while −23.5
>   becomes −24, as does −24.5.
>
> This method treats positive and negative values symmetrically, and is
>   therefore free of sign bias. More importantly, for reasonable
>   distributions of y values, the expected (average) value of the rounded
>   numbers is the same as that of the original numbers. However, this
>   rule will introduce a towards-zero bias for even numbers, and a
>   towards-infinity bias for odd ones.
>
> This variant of the round-to-nearest method is also called **unbiased
>   rounding, convergent rounding, statistician's rounding, Dutch
>   rounding, Gaussian rounding, odd-even rounding** or **bankers'
>   rounding**, and is widely used in bookkeeping.
>
> This is the default rounding mode used in IEEE 754 computing functions
>   and operators.

```
>>> "%.2f"%20.325
'20.32'
>>> "%.2f"%20.335
'20.34'
>>> "%.2f"%20.345
'20.34'
>>> "%.2f"%20.355
'20.36'
```

So the real question should be *why does the third case fail?*

`203.25` can be expressed exactly in the floating point representation, however `0.1` cannot, it turns out to be a tiny bit more than `0.1`

```
>>> 0.1*203.25
20.325000000000003
```

So it gets rounded up

Answer (score 2):

This probably is part of the answer:

```
>>> a*.1
20.325000000000003
>>> a/10
20.325
```

See @gnibblers explanation about how IEEE 754 rounding is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specific details about why those cases don't work as expected, but if you want strict accuracy with your floats, use something like [the decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no fail. See [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use printf to see what's happening

```
 print '%0.20f'%20.325
 20.32499999999999928946
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python docs for [`round()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round) point to the answer.  Basically, floating point [can't represent some numbers exactly](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues).  For instance, `0.1` ends up looking like `0.10000000000000001`.  This imprecision can sometimes lead to unexpected results.  It's really quite difficult to get calculations within a given range of tolerance with floating point numbers.  The reason the `0.1 * a` calculation works in your case, is because it's ever so slightly biased in your desired direction of rounding.

If you really need precision, you should look at using the [Decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).  Working with decimal numbers can also be a chore, but it does make it a bit easier to get the precision you desire.